# Improving accuracy of single character recognition with low-resolution image

Tags: tesseract, python-tesseract

I have a set of images all the same size that contain a single character, roughly in the same position each time. These images are all 80x75 pixels and have a purely white background and purely black character.

Here are some examples of my images:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Diz84.jpg

So far, I am having very poor accuracy using this configuration (single character mode and character whitelist):

```
pytesseract.image_to_string(x, config="-c tessedit
_char_whitelist=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
--psm 10
-l osd
")
```

Any help would be great, thank you.

Edit: I've tried resizing the images to something larger, like 800 x 750, but still have the same issue. Here's what the characters are thought to be:

- c -> p
- f -> l
- j -> l
- k -> g
- t -> l
- v -> y
- x -> m
- y -> y

Comment: Any reason why you are using .png image rather that .jpg? If you can get the dpi, then try --dpi nn. Also I expect a single character will be more difficult to ocr than a string of characters, even with --psm 10.